# What is the most efficient way to determine collision path

Tags: collision-detection, linear-algebra, objects

I am trying to create a game in which I need to know if two objects will collide in the future, and when. I have both object's position, radius (they are circles) and velocity.

A specific example of where this could be used is in a game with an asteroid field. The asteroids position, radius and a constant linear velocity. I want to determine if on their current trajectory, will they crash. If yes, in how much time.

I have tried to set up the position of the objects as a function of time:
P(t) = o + v(t)

Where P(t) is the new position, o is the original position v is the velocity and t is time.

Using this for both objects and attempting to solve for t, I get a very messy and long equation.

Comment: Get the line equations for both objects' paths and find the intersection.

Comment: That only works if the objects are travelling perpendicularly to one another or if they were singular points. Imagine them travelling at the same speed side by side close to being parallel. They would collide before the POI because they have a radius.

Comment: This Math.SE question may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/finding-points-on-two-linear-lines-which-are-a-particular-distance-apart (the "particular distance" would be the radius1+radius2). This will give multiple solutions for each line, but then you take the respectively nearer points.

Comment: Alternatively, as a poor man's solution, you can iteratively calculate points on the trajectories, check the distance between them, and when the comparsion changes between < and > radius, repeat inside that range with smaller steps, until you find a solution. But this will be *very* slow, and possibly even slower if the trajectories and speeds change.

Comment: Here's some more ideas: Rotate both trajectories such as one of them has slope 0, and then solve the other one for some *y* which would be *r1+r2*. Then you'll have points, be able to measure distances and then calculate time.

Comment: Thanks. I've been working on it and came with a possible solution. Could you evaluate the position as a function of time like I'm the question, but analyze one object from frame of reference of the other. Using relative velocity. One object would have velocity of zero and the other would be a sum of the 2 velocity. Them you could determine whether or not the moving object will arrive at the constant position.

Comment: Really nice train of thought. How would you transform this back into the non-relative space?

Comment: You wouldn't have to. With the relative positions and velocities, you could directly calculate for time by rearranging the equation: t=(p2-p1x)/v. P1 and p2 are the current positions of the objects. Solve for the X and y components separate to get a tx and ty. If tx and ty are equal, the objects collide.